# Институт открыт для всех при одном условии: принимаются только дети богатых родителей

Tags: синтаксис

> Институт открыт для всех при одном условии: **принимаются только дети
>   богатых родителей.**

Помогите пожалуйста определить: что "*принимаются только дети богатых родителей*" с синтаксической точки зрения? 
Если я правильно интерпретирую, после двоеточия называется условие. Но это не придаточное условия. Простое предложение?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Это бессоюзное сложное предложение,** так как содержит  две предикативные основы (институт открыт и принимаются дети), но не содержит союза.

Соответственно, связь является бессоюзной, отношение между частями предложения выражается интонацией и дополнительными структурными элементами.

В данном случае второе предложение поясняет первое предложение, в котором содержится **сочетание "при одном условии"**, требующее пояснения.

В таких случаях на письме обычно ставится двоеточие, а в устной речи делается предупредительная пауза.

Такое бессоюзное предложение можно перестроить в СПП с придаточным условным:

Институт открыт для всех,  **при том условии что** принимаются только дети богатых родителей. **При условии если, при том условии что** ― это предложные обороты условной семантики + союз ЕСЛИ, ЧТО, они образуют **сложный союз**.

Comment: большое спасибо  что понятно объясняете! : )

Answer (score 1):

> Если я правильно интерпретирую, после двоеточия называется условие. Но
>   это не придаточное условия. Простое предложение?

Это не придаточное.

Примерный ход ваших рассуждений должен быть таким. 
Придаточные в русском языке бывают только в сложноподчиненных предложениях (ССП), а они присоединяются только с помощью подчинительных союзов. Поскольку эта часть предложения содержит собственную грамматическую основу ("дети принимаются"), предложение не может быть простым.

Остаётся только признать ***предложение сложносочиненным, а часть после двоеточия - одним из простых, составляющих такое ССП.***

***С помощью двоеточия присоединяются предложения, разъясняющие или указывающие на причину того, о чем говорится в первой части*** (не только условие, это вообще не самый частый случай).

> § 161. Двоеточие ставится после предложения, за которым следует одно
>   или несколько предложений, не соединенных с первым посредством cоюзов
>   и заключающих в себе:
>
> а) разъяснение или раскрытие содержания того, о чем говорится в первом
>   предложении, например:
>
> Я не ошибся: старик не отказался от предлагаемого стакана. Пушкин
>
> Сверх того, заботы большого семейства беспрестанно мучили ее: то
>   кормление грудного ребенка не шло, то нянька ушла, то, как теперь,
>   заболел один из детей. Л. Толстой
>
> Тут открылась картина довольно занимательная: широкая сакля, которой
>   крыша опиралась на два законченных столба, была полна народа.
>   Лермонтов

(Правила-56)
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/157-dvoe

Ваше предложение больше всего напоминает третий пример, из Лермонтова (только он там осложнен внутренним придаточным).

Пример из Пушкина грамматически тот же, но там в первой части есть слово "ошибся", для которого потом идет прямое раскрытие содержания, его можно и под другое правило подвести:

> § 162. Двоеточие ставится между двумя предложениями, не соединенными
>   посредством союзов, если в первом предложении такими глаголами, как
>   видеть, смотреть, слышать, знать, чувствовать и т. п.,
>   (там же)

А пример из Толстого еще и под правило о перечислении можно подвести, там тоже двоеточие требуется.

Comment: *Остаётся только признать предложение сложносочиненным*. А вас кем остаётся признать?   Очередная двойка вам, гражданин @Мимоходов? Не различаем ССП и БСП? А воды-то налили, воды... И с таким умным видом...

Answer (score 0):

Это бессоюзное сложное предложение. Соответственно, выделенная вами часть – одна из основ.

Comment: Какой контекст?! Господа модераторы, вы, когда копипастите стандартные фразы, хоть немного думайте, что пишете. Вот какой здесь может быть "контекст"? И кто после этого опускает рейтинг ресурса – я с правильными, хоть и не слишком развернутыми ответами (что здесь разворачивать?) или вы с бездумными окриками? По-вашему, чем больше воды, тем лучше? Никто ее не читает, всем нужны четкие ответы.